# How to, On fling Collapsing toolbar, collapse toolbar and scroll recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

What I want:

When I fling(up) the collapsing toolbar, the toolbar should collapse completely and then recyclerview should scroll in a single fling. Exactly as in WhatsApp contacts.

What I have:

When I fling only the toolbar collapses and in order to scroll the recyclerview, I have to scroll again, Thus requires 2 flings. Other things are working fine

Comment: We're gonna need some code to identify the problem